# Trying to autologin in webpage through VBS

Tags: html, vbscript

Login page

[image]

HTML code

```
<ul class="login_screen_mask">
   <li><label for="username">Username:</label><input tabindex="1" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; padding: 1px; opacity: 0.99;"></li>
   <li><label for="password">Password:</label><input tabindex="2" type="password" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; padding: 1px; opacity: 0.99;"></li>
   <li>
      <div><input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; border-width: 0px; opacity: 0.99;"><span>Remember my login (uses cookie)</span></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is code for a login page in which the username and password are given but are linked with input tag. That tag also does not have id so I need to go to class "login_screen_mask" and search for the input tag for username and passoword. I'm able to search everything but not able to insert value in that input box. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set objIE = MyBrowser.document
2. For Each ELEMENT In objIE.getElementsByClassName("login_screen_mask")
3. If ELEMENT.className = "login_screen_mask" Then
4. MsgBox (ELEMENT.innerHTML)
5. For Each ELEMENT1 In ELEMENT.all
6. If ELEMENT1.tagName = "INPUT" Then
7. ELEMENT1.setAttribute //// What value should i put
8. MsgBox (ELEMENT1.outerHTML)`enter code here`